# Is it possible to list tokens build on upgradeable smart contracts on DEX?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

Is it possible and is it a good practice to use upgradeability (transparent, UUPS) for ERC20 tokens?
And is it possible to list and upgrade them on DEX like Pancakeswap etc... ?

If this is possible, I also wonder if it wouldnt create a security breach as you could change whatever you want in your smart contract after listing the token?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create an upgradable ERC20 contract, and it is also possible to list it on pancakeswap. You just need to provide liquidity for your token.
If you do that, your token hasn't reliability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Then sould we really consider all upgradeable ERC20 tokens as not reliable?

Comment: No it's not. In fact, USDC is an upgradable token, but it's still a reliable stable coin.